# How can I get a value from a cell of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have constructed a condition that extracts exactly one row from my dataframe:

```py
d2 = df[(df['l_ext']==l_ext) & (df['item']==item) & (df['wn']==wn) & (df['wd']==1)]
```

Now I would like to take a value from a particular column:

```py
val = d2['col_name']
```

But as a result, I get a dataframe that contains one row and one column (i.e., one cell). It is not what I need. I need one value (one float number). How can I do it in pandas?

Comment: If you tried some of these answers but ended up with a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986) for an explanation of the warning and possible workarounds/solutions.

Comment: `df['col'].iloc[0]` is faster than `df.iloc[0]['col']`

Answer (score 812, accepted):

If you have a DataFrame with only one row, then access the first (only) row as a Series using *[iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)*, and then the value using the column name:

```
In [3]: sub_df
Out[3]:
          A         B
2 -0.133653 -0.030854

In [4]: sub_df.iloc[0]
Out[4]:
A   -0.133653
B   -0.030854
Name: 2, dtype: float64

In [5]: sub_df.iloc[0]['A']
Out[5]: -0.13365288513107493
```

Comment: Note that this solution returns a Series, not a value!

Comment: @mLstudent33 It is iloc for the call to the row, and then the column name is given

Comment: Warning. `pandas.DataFrame.iloc` is deprecated since version 2.2.0

Answer (score 375):

These are fast access methods for scalars:

```
In [15]: df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
          A         B         C
0 -0.074172 -0.090626  0.038272
1 -0.128545  0.762088 -0.714816
2  0.201498 -0.734963  0.558397
3  1.563307 -1.186415  0.848246
4  0.205171  0.962514  0.037709

In [17]: df.iat[0, 0]
Out[17]: -0.074171888537611502

In [18]: df.at[0, 'A']
Out[18]: -0.074171888537611502
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot. But whereas you can do `.iloc[-1]['A']` you cannot do `at[-1,'A']` to get the last row entry

Comment: this should be the answer because we don't copy in memory an useless line to get only one element inside.

Comment: @hartmut You can always just do `at[df.index[-1],'A']`

Comment: I like this answer the best. You can also refer to named indexes, which makes your code more readable:
`df.at['my_row_name', 'my_column_name']`

Answer (score 320):

You can turn your 1x1 dataframe into a [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array, then access the first and only value of that array:

```
val = d2['col_name'].values[0]
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer since it does not return a pandas.series, and it's the simplest.

Comment: As of now, this works in pandas as well, no need to have advantage over methods available in pandas, it is a method available in pandas.

Answer (score 53):

It doesn't need to be complicated:

```
val = df.loc[df.wd==1, 'col_name'].values[0]
```

Answer (score 52):

Most answers are using *[iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)* which is good for selection by position.

If you need [selection-by-label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-label), *[loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)* would be more convenient.

> For getting a value explicitly (equiv to deprecated
> df.get_value('a','A'))
>
> ```
> # This is also equivalent to df1.at['a','A']
> In [55]: df1.loc['a', 'A']
> Out[55]: 0.13200317033032932
> ```

Answer (score 33):

I needed the value of one cell, selected by column and index names.
This solution worked for me:

`df.loc[1,:].values[0]`

Comment: This create a slice, which can be memory consuming

Answer (score 25):

It looks like changes after pandas 10.1 or 13.1.

I upgraded from 10.1 to 13.1. Before, *[iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)* is not available.

Now with 13.1, `iloc[0]['label']` gets a single value array rather than a scalar.

Like this:

```
lastprice = stock.iloc[-1]['Close']
```

Output:

```
date
2014-02-26 118.2
name:Close, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 19):

The quickest and easiest options I have found are the following. *501* represents the row index.

```
df.at[501, 'column_name']
df.get_value(501, 'column_name')
```

Comment: `get_value` is deprecated now(v0.21.0 RC1 (October 13, 2017))[reference is here](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecations) `.get_value and .set_value on Series, DataFrame, Panel, SparseSeries, and SparseDataFrame are deprecated in favor of using .iat[] or .at[] accessors (GH15269)`

Answer (score 12):

In later versions, you can fix it by simply doing:

```
val = float(d2['col_name'].iloc[0])
```

Answer (score 9):

```
df_gdp.columns
```

> Index([u'Country', u'Country Code', u'Indicator Name', u'Indicator Code',
>          u'1960', u'1961', u'1962', u'1963', u'1964', u'1965', u'1966', u'1967',
>          u'1968', u'1969', u'1970', u'1971', u'1972', u'1973', u'1974', u'1975',
>          u'1976', u'1977', u'1978', u'1979', u'1980', u'1981', u'1982', u'1983',
>          u'1984', u'1985', u'1986', u'1987', u'1988', u'1989', u'1990', u'1991',
>          u'1992', u'1993', u'1994', u'1995', u'1996', u'1997', u'1998', u'1999',
>          u'2000', u'2001', u'2002', u'2003', u'2004', u'2005', u'2006', u'2007',
>          u'2008', u'2009', u'2010', u'2011', u'2012', u'2013', u'2014', u'2015',
>          u'2016'],
>         dtype='object')

```
df_gdp[df_gdp["Country Code"] == "USA"]["1996"].values[0]
```

> 8100000000000.0

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if this is a good practice, but I noticed I can also get just the value by casting the series as `float`.

E.g.,

```
rate
```

> 3    0.042679

> Name: Unemployment_rate, dtype: float64

```
float(rate)
```

> 0.0426789

Comment: Does that work with a multi-element series as well?

Answer (score 7):

I've run across this when using dataframes with MultiIndexes and found [squeeze](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) useful.

From the documentation:

> Squeeze 1 dimensional axis objects into scalars.
>
> Series or DataFrames with a single element are squeezed to a scalar.
> DataFrames with a single column or a single row are squeezed to a
> Series. Otherwise the object is unchanged.

```
# Example for a dataframe with MultiIndex
> import pandas as pd

> df = pd.DataFrame(
                    [
                        [1, 2, 3],
                        [4, 5, 6],
                        [7, 8, 9]
                    ],
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [('i', 1), ('ii', 2), ('iii', 3)] ),
                    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')] )
)

> df
       A  B  C
       a  b  c
i   1  1  2  3
ii  2  4  5  6
iii 3  7  8  9

> df.loc['ii', 'B']
   b
2  5

> df.loc['ii', 'B'].squeeze()
5
```

Note that while `df.at[]` also works (if you aren't needing to use conditionals) you then still AFAIK need to specify all levels of the MultiIndex.

Example:

```
> df.at[('ii', 2), ('B', 'b')]
5
```

I have a dataframe with a six-level index and two-level columns, so only having to specify the outer level is quite helpful.

Answer (score 6):

For pandas 0.10, where [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is unavailable, filter a `DF` and get the first row data for the column `VALUE`:

```
df_filt = df[df['C1'] == C1val & df['C2'] == C2val]
result = df_filt.get_value(df_filt.index[0],'VALUE')
```

If there is more than one row filtered, obtain the first row value. There will be an exception if the filter results in an empty data frame.

Comment: `get_value` is deprecated now(v0.21.0 RC1 (October 13, 2017)) [reference is here](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecations) `.get_value and .set_value on Series, DataFrame, Panel, SparseSeries, and SparseDataFrame are deprecated in favor of using .iat[] or .at[] accessors (GH15269)`

Comment: But `iat` or `at` cannot get the value based on the column name.

Answer (score 5):

If a single row was filtered from a dataframe, one way to get a scalar value from a single cell is `squeeze()` (or `item()`):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5), 'B': range(5)})
d2 = df[df['A'].le(5) & df['B'].eq(3)]
val = d2['A'].squeeze()                 # 3

val = d2['A'].item()                    # 3
```

In fact, `item()` may be called on the index, so `item` + `at` combo could work.

```py
msk = df['A'].le(5) & df['B'].eq(3)
val = df.at[df.index[msk].item(), 'B']  # 3
```

In fact, the latter method is much faster than any other method listed here to get a single cell value.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10000), 'B': range(10000)})
msk = df['A'].le(5) & df['B'].eq(3)

%timeit df.at[df.index[msk].item(), 'A']
# 31.4 µs ± 5.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit df.loc[msk, 'A'].squeeze()
# 143 µs ± 8.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit df.loc[msk, 'A'].item()
# 125 µs ± 1.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit df.loc[msk, 'A'].iat[0]
# 125 µs ± 1.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit df[msk]['A'].values[0]
# 189 µs ± 8.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 4):

Converting it to integer worked for me but if you need float it is also simple:

```
int(sub_df.iloc[0])
```

for float:

```
float(sub_df.iloc[0])
```

Comment: But the question says *"I need one value (one float number)."*.

Comment: added float version too. Thx for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

Using `.item()` returns a scalar (not a `Series`), and it **only** works if there is a single element selected. It's much safer than `.values[0]` which will return the first element regardless of how many are selected.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,2], 'b': [4,5,6]})
>>> df[df['a'] == 1]['a']  # Returns a Series
0    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
>>> df[df['a'] == 1]['a'].item()
1
>>> df2 = df[df['a'] == 2]
>>> df2['b']
1    5
2    6
Name: b, dtype: int64
>>> df2['b'].values[0]
5
>>> df2['b'].item()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 331, in item
    raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it does inform user about multiple matches (if any) - through raising an exception

Answer (score 0):

**Display the data from a certain cell in pandas dataframe**

*Using dataframe.iloc*,

> Dataframe.iloc should be used when given index is the actual index made when the pandas dataframe is created.

Avoid using dataframe.iloc on custom indices.

```
print(df['REVIEWLIST'].iloc[df.index[1]])
```

*Using dataframe.loc*,

> Use dataframe.loc if you're using a custom index it can also be used instead of iloc too even the dataframe contains default indices.

```
print(df['REVIEWLIST'].loc[df.index[1315]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values like this:

```
df[(df['column1']==any_value) & (df['column2']==any_value) & (df['column']==any_value)]['column_with_values_to_get']
```

And you can add `(df['columnx']==any_value)` as much as you want

Answer (score -3):

To get the full row's value as JSON (instead of a Serie):

```py
row = df.iloc[0]
```

Use the `to_json` method like below:

```py
row.to_json()
```

Comment: How is json involved in this question?

Comment: Re *"Serie"*: Do you mean *"[Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)"*?