# How to get scalar value on a cell using conditional indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe shown below. I need to get the scalar value of column B, dependent on the value of A (which is a variable in my script). I'm trying the loc() function but it returns a Series instead of a scalar value. How do I get the scalar value()?

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2], 'B' : [4,5,6]})
>>> x
   A  B
0  0  4
1  1  5
2  2  6

>>> x.loc[x['A'] == 2]['B']
2    6
Name: B, dtype: int64

>>> type(x.loc[x['A'] == 2]['B'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a value from a cell of a data frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-data-frame)

Comment: I did read the post referenced above. My issue is the conditional indexing part (i.e., x['A'] == 2). Not sure how to get it to work with at(), iat(). Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First of all, you're better off accessing both the row and column indices from the `.loc`:

```
x.loc[x['A'] == 2, 'B']
```

Second, you can always get at the underlying numpy matrix using `.values` on a series or dataframe:

```
In : x.loc[x['A'] == 2, 'B'].values[0]
Out: 6
```

Finally, if you're not interested in the original question's "conditional indexing", there are also specific accessors designed to get a single scalar value from a DataFrame: [`dataframe.at[index, column]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at) or [`dataframe.iat[i, j]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) (these are similar to `.loc[]` and `.iloc[]` but designed for quick access to a single value).

Comment: "you're better off accessing both the row and column indices from the .loc" I am wondering what the reason for this is. What do you mean? Why is this better than the way posted in the OP?Thanks

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Doing `.values[0]` just to get the actual cell value is so clunky. Pandas developers should really improve this.

Comment: `get_value` is deprecated now(v0.21.0 RC1 (October 13, 2017)) [reference is here](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecations) `.get_value and .set_value on Series, DataFrame, Panel, SparseSeries, and SparseDataFrame are deprecated in favor of using .iat[] or .at[] accessors (GH15269)`

Comment: `x.set_index('A').at[2, 'B']`

Comment: Is there any reason not to use min(x['B'][x['A'] == 2]) ? The use of min() seems a but bodgy, but to me the syntax is more logical.

Comment: The suggested answer uses `.values`. More recent versions of Pandas documentation suggest using `to_numpy` instead.

Answer (score 4):

elaborating on @ShineZhang comment:

`x.set_index('A').at[2, 'B']`

6

`pd.__version__`

u'0.22.0'

Comment: This answer is exceedingly brief.  Perhaps you could provide a little bit of explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html#pandas.Series.squeeze):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0, 1, 2], 'B' : [4, 5, 6]})

   A  B
0  0  4
1  1  5
2  2  6

df.loc[df['A'] == 2, 'B'].squeeze()
```

Output:

```
6
```