# Extract value from single row of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in a relational database format (linked by ID's over various .csv files).

I know that each data frame contains only one value of an ID, and I'd like to know the simplest way to extract values from that row.

What I'm doing now:

```
# the group has only one element
purchase_group = purchase_groups.get_group(user_id)
price = list(purchase_group['Column_name'])[0]
```

The third row is bothering me as it seems ugly, however I'm not sure what is the workaround. The grouping (I guess) assumes that there might be multiple values and returns a `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` object, while I'd like just a row returned.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you want just the value and not a df/series then call [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) and index the first element `[0]` so just:

```
price = purchase_group['Column_name'].values[0]
```

will work.

Comment: this is what I tend to use, but I must say that it still feels a little clunky.

Comment: Yeah, it does feel clunky. Part of me wants to see a new feature made for conciseness in these kind of scenarios. Something like `df.sel(col: str|int = 0, row: str|int = 0)` where row can be supplied as a string indexer or row number, and column can be supplied as the column header or name, both of which defaulting to 0. `col` being the first positional argument because, imo, that suits a DataFrame better in this context (opposed to a Series, which is probably what someone is working with anyways if they'd benefit from something like `df.sel(row: str|int = 0, col: str|int = 0)`).

Comment: Edit: It exists `at` and `iat` such as `df.at[0, 'A']`. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-can-i-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party here, but `purchase_group['Column Name'].item()` is now available and is cleaner than some other solutions

Answer (score 8):

If `purchase_group` has single row then doing `purchase_group = purchase_group.squeeze()` would make it into a series so you could simply call `purchase_group['Column_name']` to get your values

Answer (score 0):

This method is intuitive; for example to get the first row (list from a list of lists) of values from the dataframe:

```
np.array(df)[0]
```