# How do I set tuple value to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

What i want to do should be very simple. Essentially, I have some dataframe, I need assign some tuple value to some column.

for example:

```
pd_tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3))
pd_tmp["new_column"] = ("a",2)
```

I just need a new column with tuple value, what should i do?

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

The previous code gets the error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can wrap the tuples in a list:

```
import pandas as pd
pd_tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3))
pd_tmp["new_column"] = [("a",2)] * len(pd_tmp)

pd_tmp
#          0           1           2    new_column
#0  0.835350    0.338516    0.914184    (a, 2)
#1  0.007327    0.418952    0.741958    (a, 2)
#2  0.758607    0.464525    0.400847    (a, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for something similar, but in my case I wanted the tuple to be a combination of the existing columns, not just a fixed value. I found the solution below, which I share hoping it will be useful to others, like me.

```py
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
      A     B
0     1     2
1    11    22
2   111   222
3  1111  2222

In [25]: df['D'] = df[['A','B']].apply(tuple, axis=1)

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
      A     B             D
0     1     2        (1, 2)
1    11    22      (11, 22)
2   111   222    (111, 222)
3  1111  2222  (1111, 2222)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` with a `lambda` that returns the `tuple`

```
pd_tmp.assign(newc_olumn=pd_tmp.apply(lambda x: ('a', 2), 1))

          0         1         2 newc_olumn
0  0.373564  0.806956  0.106911     (a, 2)
1  0.332508  0.711735  0.230347     (a, 2)
2  0.516232  0.343266  0.813759     (a, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The doc of [`series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series).

> Series is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding any data
>   type (integers, strings, floating point numbers, Python objects,
>   etc.). The axis labels are collectively referred to as the index. The
>   basic method to create a Series is to call:
>
> ```
> >>> s = pd.Series(data, index=index)
> ```
>
> Here, data can be many different things:
>
> - a Python dict
> - an ndarray
> - a scalar value (like 5)

So `Series` won't take tuple type directly.
@Psidom's answer is to make the tuple as the element of a `ndarray`.

If you are asking about how to [set a cell of Series/Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16729574/1278112) that's an asked question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the trick is to put a tuple inside of a list [('a', 2)] for each value
and multiply to the number of rows or use apply/lambda
Here are some extra related cases:

If only one digit in a tuple add comma:

```
pd.DataFrame({'no_comma': [(1.9)], 'with_comma': [(1.9,)]})
```

To put a tuple into index:

```
size = 3  
pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,size), [('a',2)]*size )
```