# accessing a pandas DataFrame cell

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a pandas issue.

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
     A      B       C      D
0   max   kate    marie   John
1   kate  marie   max     john
2   john  max     kate    marie
3   marie john    kate    max
```

And I need to access, for instance, the cell in row 0, column D.

I tried using df.iloc[0, 3] but it returns the whole D column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: `df.iloc[0, 3]` works fine for me

Comment: It must work. You need to look elsewhere for the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`df.iloc[0]['D']`

or

`df.loc[0,'D']`

Documentation reference [DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

To get the value at a location.

Comment: you are likely to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) warning if you do a chained assignment. It should be avoided

Comment: @anky_91 what about using `df.loc[0,'D']` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.iloc[0]["D"]
```

seems to do the trick

Comment: you are likely to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) if you do a chained assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this for your solution

```
# Import pandas package
import pandas as pd

# Define a dictionary containing employee data
data = {'Name': ['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
        'Age': [27, 24, 22, 32],
        'Address': ['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Allahabad', 'Kannauj'],
        'Qualification': ['Msc', 'MA', 'MCA', 'Phd']}

# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(pd)
```

Then you got the table like this

[image]

if you want the name in the 0-th row and in 0-th column("Name")

***synthax = dataframe.iloc[row-index]['ColumnName']***

```
print(df.iloc[0]['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if your Dataframe name is `df`.

```
df.iloc[0,3]
Out[15]: 'John'
```