# How to convert dataframe to string in Python

Tags: python, pandas

We're working on a python project, where we're using **SQLalchemy** to retrieve data from our **MySQL** database. We have succeeded in establishing a connection to the database:

```py
engine = create_engine("mysql://xxx:xxx@localhost/xxx")
conn = engine.connect()
```

When we are connected, we are retrieving first and last timestamp, so we can set up a range and an interval of 20 minutes. We are doing so by using following line of code:

```py
lastLpnTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1"', conn).astype(str).values
firstLpnTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1"', conn).astype(str).values.tolist()
```

We then want to round down the `timestamp` for `firstLpnTime`, so the minutes will be round down to either xx.00, xx.20, xx:40, so for example 15:09:25 will round down to 15:00:00

```py
firstLpnTime = pd.to_datetime(firstLpnTime).round('20T')
```

And then we set up a range between `firstLpnTime` and `lastLpnTime` and an interval of 20 min

```py
index = pd.date_range(start=firstLpnTime.min(), end=lastLpnTime.max(), freq='20T')
```

However... we are receiving an error for this line of code:

```py
firstLpnTime = pd.to_datetime(firstLpnTime).round('20T')
```

Error message is saying:

```sh
TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

Variable `firstLpnTime` has an `astype(str)`, so it should be a string, so we don't get why it's not working. Maybe the datatype is not changing to string?

The output, when I print `firstLpnTime`, is: `[['2019-07-26 15:09:25']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `firstLpnTime` is nested within an array.

So, you can try taking first index from this variable and then casting it using pandas.

```
firstLpnTime = pd.to_datetime(firstLpnTime[0]).round('20T')
```

Then, `firstLpnTime` should give this result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-26 15:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: pandas.read_sql returns a dataframe. Then, you are using dataframe.values which returns numpy.ndarray. Hence, you are getting nested array.

Comment: Can this be prevented? And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: You can try using dataframe directly. It should be much easier as you can extract single value easily then perform casting.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what to look for in the answer from the link you provided. Do you mind elaborating? That would make my day!

Comment: Added new answer for that! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid value nested within array, you can use **DataFrame** directly as shown in below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://xxxx:xxxx@localhost:3306/test')
conn = engine.connect()

lastLpnTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MAX(timestamp) as max_time FROM 
     test.test_table WHERE topic = "lpn1";', conn).iloc[0]['max_time']
firstLpnTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MIN(timestamp) as min_time FROM 
     test.test_table WHERE topic = "lpn1"', conn).iloc[0]['min_time']

firstLpnTime = firstLpnTime.round('20T')
firstLpnTime
```

This will provide the expected output in Pandas Timestamp class.

```
Timestamp('2019-07-26 15:00:00')
```

Hope it helps! :)