# How to get cell value from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

So currently, I ask the user for the column name input and the row input but I don't know how to get the cell value.

```
import pandas as pd 

data_column = input("what column do you want to choose")
print(data_column)
data_row = input("What row do you want to choose")
print(data_row)
```

I have tried with iloc and loc but it doesn't return the cell value.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The second section of the user guide is titled "Indexing and Selecting Data" https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: _I have tried with iloc and loc but it doesn't return the cell value._ That's too vague. This seems like an extremely basic question, have you actually done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the value of a specific cell by using

```
data_table.iloc[data_row, data_column]
```

Remember that

```
input("x")
```

returns a string, so you'd have to cast it into an int if you want to use the variable directly.

```
data_column = int(input("what column do you want to choose"))
```