# Copy pandas value only to dictionary: suppress index

Tags: python, pandas

I need to copy values only from a DF to a dict for the purposes of a display function that takes a dict as an argument.

My dataframe is called `databases` in the following excerpt.

```
DB_stat_reporting = dict()
report_month = databases.loc[databases['Date'] == reporting_month]
last_year    = databases.loc[databases['Date'] == past_year]

report_month
```

Output:

```
    Date        Circ    EB  Mag     bla     drive   Total   Digi
12  2019-12-01  118324  133 1084    4928    17513   141982  23658
```

I need to pass the values only to a dictionary:

```
DB_stat_reporting['Circ']     = report_month['Circ']
DB_stat_reporting['Circ']
```

Produces:

```
12    118324
```

I need to run some stats on it so it needs to stay an int but I do not want the index or brackets, etc. to be printed.

Expected output:

```
118324
```

This seemed like such a simple thing but I can not get it to do this.

Comment: Have you done any research? This seems like basic Pandas functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: @AMC I basically overthought this. Project rush and brain freeze. Should I delete this?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get the value itself without the index:

```
DB_stat_reporting = dict()
DB_stat_reporting['Circ'] = report_month.loc[12, 'Circ']
```

Or [`Series.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
DB_stat_reporting = dict()
DB_stat_reporting['Circ'] = report_month['Circ'].iat[0]
```

```
print(DB_stat_reporting)

{'Circ': 118324}
```

Comment: KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'

Comment: You have to select the correct index, so in your case use `12`, so it would be `report_month.loc[12, 'Circ']`

Comment: Series.iat example worked using 0. Why does that one work while the first one requires the correct index?

Comment: `loc` is labeled based indexing, so in this case `12` is the label. `iat` is based on position.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you! I will accept this answer once the timer runs out.