# Extract nested dictionary from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

The metadata column contains nested dictionaries in each row. Data looks like this:

```
id_x          source    metadata
144275745e    html      {}
e87357867f    html      {}
```

I don't know the precise structure of a dictionary but I do know it is a nested dictionary. Before extracting the values that I need I want to see how the dictionary looks like - it is in json format. Is there a way to just print out the value from `metadata` column for `144275745e` id_x?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. There are no nested dictionaries in what you provided. Are you saying that the `metadata` column contains nested dicts in each row? Can you [edit] to provide a more complete sample input and an example of your desired output?

Comment: Are you just asking how to access a particular element of the DataFrame? If so, there are plenty of resources on the subject already.

Comment: In light of your answer, this is clearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16729574/11301900.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = df['metadata'].values[0]
```