# Pandas: Filtering and selecting a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    Indicator        Value        Subregion    Territory  Year
0   Indic1        1115.000000    Southern Asia  Afghanistan  2009
1   Indic1         983.000000    Southern Asia  Afghanistan  2010
2   Indic2        1231.000000    Southern Asia  Afghanistan  2011
...
```

I want to get the Subregion of a certain row. I can select the row like this:

```
df.loc[(df['Territory'] == 'Afghanistan') & (df['Year'] == 2009)]
```

Which, as expected, results in:

```
       Indicator     Value      Subregion    Territory  Year
8       Indic1     1115.000000  Southern Asia  Afghanistan  2009
```

Now when I use

```
df.loc[(df['Territory'] == 'Afghanistan') & (df['Year'] == 2009)]['Subregion']
```

I would expect the result to be the string **Southern Asia**. However, what I get is :

```
13    Southern Asia
Name: Subregion, dtype: object
```

Why is that and how do I just get the string from this?

Comment: _how do I just get the string from this?_ What is the type of that object?

Comment: The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031070/5057078

Comment: @Brambor Yes that solved the problem, thank you :)