# adding values into pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add new values from a previous df into a newly created df.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['org1_name','org1_desc','org2_name','org2_desc','score'])
new_df.iloc[0,0] = previous_df.name[0]
```

`previous_df.name[0]` gives me

```
9958    SETA BioMedicals
Name: name, dtype: object
```

and I just want "SETA BioMedicals".

However, `previous_df.name[0]` keeps giving me a pandas.core.series.Series instead of a string, and when I add `to_string` to it, it just changes the type to a method instead of a string. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you'll provide values from new_df/previous_df - it will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @adhg edited the question!

Comment: Maybe his helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe

Comment: so new_df is only columns? if so - you can assign a value in position 0 because it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your new dataframe is empty so you can not insert values into iloc[0,0]. Instead you need to append the dataframe as shown below. Also note that the append method does not mutate the dataframe, so you need to assign the returned value to a variable.

```
#I imagine this is what a portion of your previous_df looks like:
previous_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['SETA BioMedicals']})

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['org1_name','org1_desc','org2_name','org2_desc','score'])
new_df = new_df.append({'org1_name': previous_df['name'][0]}, ignore_index=True)

print(new_df)
#output:
          org1_name org1_desc org2_name org2_desc score
0  SETA BioMedicals       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `squeeze` method if you want to convert your 1D axis into single value.

```
>>> pd.Series("SETA BioMedicals", index=[9958])
9958    SETA BioMedicals
dtype: object
```

```
>>> pd.Series("SETA BioMedicals", index=[9958]).squeeze()
'SETA BioMedicals'
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html