# How can i store a variable of a DataFrame and use it to send a email?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, email

I want to store a value of a dataframe and use it to send an email:

```
def config():
    sql_con_obj = SqlConnector()
    sql_con_obj.connect()
    sql_con_obj.con.commit()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM bd_opensgc.Config"
    df = pandas.read_sql_query(sql, sql_con_obj.con)
    df.to_csv("Config.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
    Emails = df['Email']
    sql_con_obj.disconnect()
    del sql_con_obj
    return Emails
```

df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------           --------------  -----
 1   Email            1 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
```

in the email function i get the Emails variable and say that

```
Emails=config()
you = Emails
msg['To'] =you
smtp.sendmail(me,you, msg.as_string())
```

and it gives me this error :

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.values` or `iloc`, otherwise you'd get the entire column that is always of type `Series`

For Example:

`Emails = df['Email'].values[0]`

Check this out:

[How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe)