# Key error when trying to get a value in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that has a column with the name "datetime". Now I would like to get a specific value from it. I tried the solutions suggested here [How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe) but I always get an "KeyError: 'datetime'"

Here is a screenshot of the dataframe
[image]

And here is what I tried:

```
print("df.at[5,'datetime']", df.at[5,"datetime"])
print("df.iloc['datetime', 5]", df.iloc[5]["datetime"])
```

Any idea, why I get this error and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you provide dataframe in text format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `datetime` is your index column so you should be able to access it through `df.index[5]`

If you want `datetime` to be a column like any other you can use `df.reset_index()`.

If you want `datetime` to be a column but also keep it as your index use:

```py
df['datetime'] = df.index
```

More generally:

```py
df[df.index.name] = df.index
```

If you need an expression rather than a statement:

```py
df.assign(**{df.index.name: df.index})
```