# how to get cell value of a pd data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am getting this rowset from remote sql

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data_df)
```

Output:

```
 ID         Date_Time    Hz_1    Hz_2    Hz_3   Hz_4    Hz_5    Hz_6    Hz_7    Hz_8
0   1 2022-09-13 17:17:29  50.592  50.592  50.852  50.84  50.819  50.816  50.803  50.789
```

How do I get the cell value for example `Hz_1` which is `50.592`

I tried

```
hz1 = data["Hz_1"][0]
```

which does not work. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I have solved it like this

hz1 = data_df.loc[0,'Hz_1']

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-can-i-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe

Comment: data.iloc[0]['Hz_1']