# How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chained-assignment, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

### Background

I just upgraded my Pandas from 0.11 to 0.13.0rc1. Now, the application is popping out many new warnings. One of them like this:

```
E:\FinReporter\FM_EXT.py:449: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  quote_df['TVol']   = quote_df['TVol']/TVOL_SCALE
```

I want to know what exactly it means?  Do I need to change something?

How should I suspend the warning if I insist to use `quote_df['TVol']   = quote_df['TVol']/TVOL_SCALE`?

### The function that gives warnings

```
def _decode_stock_quote(list_of_150_stk_str):
    """decode the webpage and return dataframe"""

    from cStringIO import StringIO

    str_of_all = "".join(list_of_150_stk_str)

    quote_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str_of_all), sep=',', names=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefg')) #dtype={'A': object, 'B': object, 'C': np.float64}
    quote_df.rename(columns={'A':'STK', 'B':'TOpen', 'C':'TPCLOSE', 'D':'TPrice', 'E':'THigh', 'F':'TLow', 'I':'TVol', 'J':'TAmt', 'e':'TDate', 'f':'TTime'}, inplace=True)
    quote_df = quote_df.ix[:,[0,3,2,1,4,5,8,9,30,31]]
    quote_df['TClose'] = quote_df['TPrice']
    quote_df['RT']     = 100 * (quote_df['TPrice']/quote_df['TPCLOSE'] - 1)
    quote_df['TVol']   = quote_df['TVol']/TVOL_SCALE
    quote_df['TAmt']   = quote_df['TAmt']/TAMT_SCALE
    quote_df['STK_ID'] = quote_df['STK'].str.slice(13,19)
    quote_df['STK_Name'] = quote_df['STK'].str.slice(21,30)#.decode('gb2312')
    quote_df['TDate']  = quote_df.TDate.map(lambda x: x[0:4]+x[5:7]+x[8:10])
    
    return quote_df
```

### More warning messages

```
E:\FinReporter\FM_EXT.py:449: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  quote_df['TVol']   = quote_df['TVol']/TVOL_SCALE
E:\FinReporter\FM_EXT.py:450: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  quote_df['TAmt']   = quote_df['TAmt']/TAMT_SCALE
E:\FinReporter\FM_EXT.py:453: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  quote_df['TDate']  = quote_df.TDate.map(lambda x: x[0:4]+x[5:7]+x[8:10])
```

Comment: Here's a context manager to temporarily set the warning level https://gist.github.com/notbanker/2be3ed34539c86e22ffdd88fd95ad8bc

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy official document explain in detail

Comment: @leonprou `df.set_value` has been deprecated. Pandas now recommends to use `.at[]` or `.iat[]` instead. docs here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

Comment: Using `df.loc[:, foo]` avoids `SettingWithCopyWarning`, whereas `df[foo]` causes `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Comment: @Asclepius df.loc[:, foo] is also giving me SettingWithCopyWarning: asking me to use Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead I don't really have any row_indexer since I want to carry out this assignment for all rows. How do I do that?

Comment: Looking up some other related solutions I did a .copy() first to create my dataframe. Then it worked even with df[foo] = ...

Answer (score 1652, accepted):

The `SettingWithCopyWarning` was created to flag potentially confusing "chained" assignments, such as the following, which does not always work as expected, particularly when the first selection returns a *copy*.  [see [GH5390](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5390) and [GH5597](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5597) for background discussion.]

```
df[df['A'] > 2]['B'] = new_val  # new_val not set in df
```

The warning offers a suggestion to rewrite as follows:

```
df.loc[df['A'] > 2, 'B'] = new_val
```

However, this doesn't fit your usage, which is equivalent to:

```
df = df[df['A'] > 2]
df['B'] = new_val
```

While it's clear that you don't care about writes making it back to the original frame (since you are overwriting the reference to it), unfortunately this pattern cannot be differentiated from the first chained assignment example. Hence the (false positive) warning. The potential for false positives is addressed in the [docs on indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), if you'd like to read further.  You can safely disable this new warning with the following assignment.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
```

---

### Other Resources

- [pandas User Guide: Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)
- [Python Data Science Handbook: Data Indexing and Selection](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.02-data-indexing-and-selection.html)
- [Real Python: SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas: Views vs Copies](https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/)
- [Dataquest: SettingwithCopyWarning: How to Fix This Warning in Pandas](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/)
- [Towards Data Science: Explaining the SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/explaining-the-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas-ebc19d799d25)

Comment: I was using a slice of a dataframe, doing modifications in that slice and was getting this error. I created this slice by doing a `.copy()` on the original dataframe, and it worked.

Comment: How should I deal with `df = df[df['A'].notnull()]`?

Comment: @Garrett please consider adding @RishabhAgrahari's comment to your answer. It's a way better idea to tell pandas you meant to manipulate a copy of the slice by calling `.copy()` on it than outright disabling the warning for all cases in your runtime.

Comment: In my case, the warning was not set on the line to modify. I filtered data on the first line and then created a calculated field on a second line. The warning is displayed for the second line and in fact the solution is to modify the first line by adding a call to .copy(). 
This is misleading and sometimes the two lines are seperated by quite a big amount of code.

Comment: Using `.copy()` on the slice is a bad workaround, because it introduces an extra, unneeded copy. A subsetting operation like `df[df.a > 2]` already creates a new dataframe, so there's no algorithmic need for an additional copy.

Comment: Summarizing: if you just want to remove the warning use: `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`. This isn't a long term fix, but it will get by.

Answer (score 845):

> #### How to deal with `SettingWithCopyWarning` and `ChainedAssignmentError` in Pandas?

This post is meant for readers who,

1. Would like to understand what this warning means
2. Would like to understand different ways of suppressing this warning
3. Would like to understand how to improve their code and follow good practices to avoid this warning in the future.

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (3, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  0  3  3  7
1  9  3  5  2  4
2  7  6  8  8  1
```

---

## What is the `SettingWithCopyWarning`?

To know how to deal with this warning, it is important to understand what it means and why it is raised in the first place.

When filtering DataFrames, it is possible slice/index a frame to return either a *view*, or a *copy*, depending on the internal layout and various implementation details. A "view" is, as the term suggests, a view into the original data, so modifying the view may modify the original object. On the other hand, a "copy" is a replication of data from the original, and modifying the copy has no effect on the original.

As mentioned by other answers, the `SettingWithCopyWarning` was created to flag "chained assignment" operations. Consider `df` in the setup above. Suppose you would like to select all values in column "B" where values in column "A" is > 5. Pandas allows you to do this in different ways, some more correct than others. For example,

```
df[df.A > 5]['B']

1    3
2    6
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

And,

```
df.loc[df.A > 5, 'B']

1    3
2    6
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

These return the same result, so if you are only reading these values, it makes no difference. So, what is the issue? The problem with chained assignment, is that it is generally difficult to predict whether a view or a copy is returned, **so this largely becomes an issue when you are attempting to assign values back.** To build on the earlier example, consider how this code is executed by the interpreter:

```
df.loc[df.A > 5, 'B'] = 4
# becomes
df.__setitem__((df.A > 5, 'B'), 4)
```

With a single `__setitem__` call to `df`. OTOH, consider this code:

```
df[df.A > 5]['B'] = 4
# becomes
df.__getitem__(df.A > 5).__setitem__('B', 4)
```

Now, depending on whether `__getitem__` returned a view or a copy, the `__setitem__` operation **may not work**.

In general, you should use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for label-based assignment, and [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for integer/positional based assignment, as the spec guarantees that they always operate on the original. Additionally, for setting a single cell, you should use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) and [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html).

More can be found in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

> **Note**
> All boolean indexing operations done with `loc` can also be done with `iloc`. The only difference is that `iloc` expects either
> integers/positions for index or a numpy array of boolean values, and
> integer/position indexes for the columns.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> df.loc[df.A > 5, 'B'] = 4
> ```
>
> Can be written nas
>
> ```
> df.iloc[(df.A > 5).values, 1] = 4
> ```
>
> And,
>
> ```
> df.loc[1, 'A'] = 100
> ```
>
> Can be written as
>
> ```
> df.iloc[1, 0] = 100
> ```
>
> And so on.

#### from pandas >= 2.0, you can enable [Copy-on-write optimizations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/copy_on_write.html#copy-on-write-optimizations) to save on memory and avoid making copies of data until written to (if possible).

This can be enabled by

```
pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = True
```

After this, attempts to make chained assignments will result in

```
ChainedAssignmentError: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a DataFrame or Series through chained assignment.
When using the Copy-on-Write mode, such chained assignment never works to update the original DataFrame or Series, because the intermediate object on which we are setting values always behaves as a copy.

Try using '.loc[row_indexer, col_indexer] = value' instead, to perform the assignment in a single step.
```

The error is raised in a similar setting to the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

---

## Just tell me how to suppress the warning!

Consider a simple operation on the "A" column of `df`. Selecting "A" and dividing by 2 will raise the warning, but the operation will work.

```
df2 = df[['A']]
df2['A'] /= 2
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

df2
     A
0  2.5
1  4.5
2  3.5
```

There are a couple ways of directly silencing this warning:

1. (recommended) **Use `loc` to slice subsets**:

   ```
    df2 = df.loc[:, ['A']]
    df2['A'] /= 2     # Does not raise
   ```
2. **Change `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment`**
   Can be set to `None`, `"warn"`, or `"raise"`. `"warn"` is the default. `None` will suppress the warning entirely, and `"raise"` will throw a `SettingWithCopyError`, preventing the operation from going through.

   ```
    pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
    df2['A'] /= 2
   ```
3. **Make a `deepcopy`**

   ```
    df2 = df[['A']].copy(deep=True)
    df2['A'] /= 2
   ```

[@Peter Cotton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas#comment62589711_20625582) in the comments, came up with a nice way of non-intrusively changing the mode (modified from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/notbanker/2be3ed34539c86e22ffdd88fd95ad8bc)) using a context manager, to set the mode only as long as it is required, and the reset it back to the original state when finished.

> ```
> class ChainedAssignent:
>     def __init__(self, chained=None):
>         acceptable = [None, 'warn', 'raise']
>         assert chained in acceptable, "chained must be in " + str(acceptable)
>         self.swcw = chained
>
>     def __enter__(self):
>         self.saved_swcw = pd.options.mode.chained_assignment
>         pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = self.swcw
>         return self
>
>     def __exit__(self, *args):
>         pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = self.saved_swcw
> ```

The usage is as follows:

```
# Some code here
with ChainedAssignent():
    df2['A'] /= 2
# More code follows
```

Or, to raise the exception

```
with ChainedAssignent(chained='raise'):
    df2['A'] /= 2

SettingWithCopyError:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

---

## The "XY Problem": What am I doing wrong?

A lot of the time, users attempt to look for ways of suppressing this exception without fully understanding why it was raised in the first place. This is a good example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), where users attempt to solve a problem "Y" that is actually a symptom of a deeper rooted problem "X". Questions will be raised based on common problems that encounter this warning, and solutions will then be presented.

> **Question 1**
> I have a DataFrame
>
> ```
> df
>        A  B  C  D  E
>     0  5  0  3  3  7
>     1  9  3  5  2  4
>     2  7  6  8  8  1
> ```
>
> I want to assign values in col "A" > 5 to 1000. My expected output is
>
> ```
>       A  B  C  D  E
> 0     5  0  3  3  7
> 1  1000  3  5  2  4
> 2  1000  6  8  8  1
> ```

Wrong way to do this:

```
df.A[df.A > 5] = 1000         # works, because df.A returns a view
df[df.A > 5]['A'] = 1000      # does not work
df.loc[df.A > 5]['A'] = 1000   # does not work
```

Right way using `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.A > 5, 'A'] = 1000
```

> **Question 2<sup>1</sup>**
> I am trying to set the value in cell (1, 'D') to 12345. My expected output is
>
> ```
>    A  B  C      D  E
> 0  5  0  3      3  7
> 1  9  3  5  12345  4
> 2  7  6  8      8  1
> ```
>
> I have tried different ways of accessing this cell, such as
> `df['D'][1]`. What is the best way to do this?
>
> <sub>1. This question isn't specifically related to the warning, but
> it is good to understand how to do this particular operation correctly
> so as to avoid situations where the warning could potentially arise in
> future.</sub>

You can use any of the following methods to do this.

```
df.loc[1, 'D'] = 12345
df.iloc[1, 3] = 12345
df.at[1, 'D'] = 12345
df.iat[1, 3] = 12345
```

> **Question 3**
> I am trying to subset values based on some condition. I have a
> DataFrame
>
> ```
>    A  B  C  D  E
> 1  9  3  5  2  4
> 2  7  6  8  8  1
> ```
>
> I would like to assign values in "D" to 123 such that "C" == 5. I
> tried
>
> ```
> df2.loc[df2.C == 5, 'D'] = 123
> ```
>
> Which seems fine but I am *still* getting the
> `SettingWithCopyWarning`! How do I fix this?

This is actually probably because of code higher up in your pipeline. Did you create `df2` from something larger, like

```
df2 = df[df.A > 5]
```

? In this case, boolean indexing will return a view, so `df2` will reference the original. What you'd need to do is assign `df2` to a *copy*:

```
df2 = df[df.A > 5].copy()
# Or,
# df2 = df.loc[df.A > 5, :]
```

> **Question 4**
> I'm trying to drop column "C" in-place from
>
> ```
>    A  B  C  D  E
> 1  9  3  5  2  4
> 2  7  6  8  8  1
> ```
>
> But using
>
> ```
> df2.drop('C', axis=1, inplace=True)
> ```
>
> Throws `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Why is this happening?

This is because `df2` must have been created as a view from some other slicing operation, such as

```
df2 = df[df.A > 5]
```

The solution here is to either make a `copy()` of `df`, or use `loc`, as before.

Comment: P.S.: Let me know if your situation is not covered under section 3's list of questions. I will amend my post.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for Question 2 to link to a question addressing the differences between loc, iloc, at, and iat.  You are probably more aware of such a question than I am, but I'm happy to seek one if it would be helpful.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754603/indexing-pandas-data-frames-integer-rows-named-columns) address the case where you want to use loc and iloc at the same time, iloc for rows and loc for columns

Comment: @cs95: Could you add  an XY description around the case where you are trying to create a new column based on simple math operations on an existing one. As in df['new_col'] = df['old_col']/2. Where 'new_col' does not yet exist. Thx

Comment: @BryanP unless I'm mistaken that should more or less be covered under the "Just tell me how to suppress the warning!" section.

Comment: @cs95: Thanks. making a copy when creating the data frame worked (in my case the structure was simple enough that `.copy()` was enough. However, this doesn't seem like just suppressing the warning. I had originally skipped that section since my goal was to fix the problem rather than to tell Pandas to ignore it. It seems using `copy()` to make the original dataframe its own thing (rather than a view and assuming it is derived from other places) seems to actually fix the underlying problem, right? Not just suppress the warning?

Comment: is there a way to do boolean indexing that explicitly returns a new object, without calling `.copy()` ? Because I want to make the new column only after slimming down the dataframe

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă loc always return a copy when slicing data.

Comment: @cs95 - thanks. Nearly everyone focusses on your questions 1 and 2. But, I had exactly the subset problem in question 3. I discovered that after the subnet is created, ```_is_copy``` is no longer None which lead me to using .copy().

Comment: Thank a lot! I always use `.loc` in my code because I was aware of the "chained assignment" problem, but I was still getting nearly random annoying `SettingWithCopyWarning` now and then. It turns out that my problem is what you cover in your "Question 3". This took me months to realise, so perhaps it should be pointed out more clearly in the documentation... anyway thanks a lot again!

Comment: Well, it seems kind of random that the "Question 3" throws "SettingWithCopyWarning" because it is a different problem (here you might be surprised that you are changing df, in other cases you might be surprised that your changes get lost). This warning is very annoying.

Comment: @cs95 what about `df["widget"].replace("foo", "bar", inplace=True)` ?

Comment: What a great explanation. Comments have many references to "Question 3", but it's "Answer 3", that solved my problem. Specifically, "This is actually probably because of code higher up in your pipeline. Did you create df2 from something larger, like df2 = df[df.A > 5]". Doh! That was exactly it. Thanks.

Comment: For pandas Series (that is, not a DataFrame), with pandas `1.5.3`, I get this warning which actually now is an error, when trying to use either `loc` or `iloc`. All I want to do is add a row in-place to a pandas Series, and it seems impossible without using `concat` of old Series and new row. Btw, despite an error is thrown, the value is being set, which is weird. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 176):

In general the point of the `SettingWithCopyWarning` is to show users (and especially new users) that they *may* be operating on a copy and not the original as they think. There *are* false positives (IOW if you know what you are doing it could be *ok*). One possibility is simply to turn off the (by default *warn*) warning as @Garrett suggest.

Here is another option:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=list('AB'))

In [2]: dfa = df.ix[:, [1, 0]]

In [3]: dfa.is_copy
Out[3]: True

In [4]: dfa['A'] /= 2
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  #!/usr/local/bin/python
```

You can set the `is_copy` flag to `False`, which will effectively turn off the check, *for that object*:

```
In [5]: dfa.is_copy = False

In [6]: dfa['A'] /= 2
```

If you explicitly copy then no further warning will happen:

```
In [7]: dfa = df.ix[:, [1, 0]].copy()

In [8]: dfa['A'] /= 2
```

The code the OP is showing above, while legitimate, and probably something I do as well, is technically a case for this warning, and not a false positive. Another way to *not* have the warning would be to do the selection operation via `reindex`, e.g.

```
quote_df = quote_df.reindex(columns=['STK', ...])
```

Or,

```
quote_df = quote_df.reindex(['STK', ...], axis=1)  # v.0.21
```

Comment: I think it's an understatement to say that there are false positives. I don't think I've ever had this warning help me, and the number of times I've had it clog up my output is insane. It's also bad programming practice: if you start ignoring the warnings in your output because you know they are pure rubbish, you can start to miss real problems. It's also annoying to have to turn off the same warnings all the time.

Answer (score 60):

Here I answer the question directly. How can we deal with it?

Make a `.copy(deep=False)` after you slice. See [pandas.DataFrame.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).

Wait, doesn't a slice return a copy? After all, this is what the warning message is attempting to say? Read the long answer:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3]})
```

This gives a warning:

```
df0 = df[df.x>2]
df0['foo'] = 'bar'
```

This does not:

```
df1 = df[df.x>2].copy(deep=False)
df1['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Both `df0` and `df1` are `DataFrame` objects, but something about them is different that enables pandas to print the warning. Let's find out what it is.

```
import inspect
slice= df[df.x>2]
slice_copy = df[df.x>2].copy(deep=False)
inspect.getmembers(slice)
inspect.getmembers(slice_copy)
```

Using your diff tool of choice, you will see that beyond a couple of addresses, the only material difference is this:

```
|          | slice   | slice_copy |
| _is_copy | weakref | None       |
```

The method that decides whether to warn is `DataFrame._check_setitem_copy` which checks `_is_copy`. So here you go. Make a `copy` so that your DataFrame is not `_is_copy`.

The warning is suggesting to use `.loc`, but if you use `.loc` on a frame that `_is_copy`, you will still get the same warning. Misleading? Yes. Annoying? You bet. Helpful? Potentially, when chained assignment is used. But it cannot correctly detect chain assignment and prints the warning indiscriminately.

Comment: Good sleuthing.  FWIW I also found that `_is_copy` is `None` for the original df and a weakref for the slice.  Further, `_is_copy()` on the slice returns all the rows of the original df.  But the reference printed by `_is_copy` is not the same as the id of the original df.  Does the slice somehow make a copy?  Also, am wondering if a shallow copy would cause some other issue down the line or with a newer version of pandas?

Comment: This answer surely deserves a separate badge for writing style.

Comment: Hands-down the most concrete and direct answer to the question. Very well put.

Answer (score 49):

### Pandas dataframe copy warning

When you go and do something like this:

```
quote_df = quote_df.ix[:,[0,3,2,1,4,5,8,9,30,31]]
```

`pandas.ix` *in this case* returns a new, stand alone dataframe.

Any values you decide to change in this dataframe, will not change the original dataframe.

This is what pandas tries to warn you about.

---

### Why `.ix` is a bad idea

The `.ix` object tries to do more than one thing, and for anyone who has read anything about clean code, this is a strong smell.

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b": [1,1,2,2]})
```

Two behaviors:

```
dfcopy = df.ix[:,["a"]]
dfcopy.a.ix[0] = 2
```

Behavior one: `dfcopy` is now a stand alone dataframe. Changing it will not change `df`

```
df.ix[0, "a"] = 3
```

Behavior two: This changes the original dataframe.

---

### Use `.loc` instead

The pandas developers recognized that the `.ix` object was quite smelly[speculatively] and thus created two new objects which helps in the accession and assignment of data. (The other being `.iloc`)

`.loc` is faster, because it does not try to create a copy of the data.

`.loc` is meant to modify your existing dataframe inplace, which is more memory efficient.

`.loc` is predictable, it has one behavior.

---

### The solution

What you are doing in your code example is loading a big file with lots of columns, then modifying it to be smaller.

The `pd.read_csv` function can help you out with a lot of this and also make the loading of the file a lot faster.

So instead of doing this

```
quote_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str_of_all), sep=',', names=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefg')) #dtype={'A': object, 'B': object, 'C': np.float64}
quote_df.rename(columns={'A':'STK', 'B':'TOpen', 'C':'TPCLOSE', 'D':'TPrice', 'E':'THigh', 'F':'TLow', 'I':'TVol', 'J':'TAmt', 'e':'TDate', 'f':'TTime'}, inplace=True)
quote_df = quote_df.ix[:,[0,3,2,1,4,5,8,9,30,31]]
```

Do this

```
columns = ['STK', 'TPrice', 'TPCLOSE', 'TOpen', 'THigh', 'TLow', 'TVol', 'TAmt', 'TDate', 'TTime']
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str_of_all), sep=',', usecols=[0,3,2,1,4,5,8,9,30,31])
df.columns = columns
```

This will only read the columns you are interested in, and name them properly. No need for using the evil `.ix` object to do magical stuff.

Answer (score 34):

This topic is really confusing with Pandas. Luckily, it has a relatively simple solution.

The problem is that it is not always clear whether data filtering operations (e.g. loc) return a copy or a view of the DataFrame. Further use of such filtered DataFrame could therefore be confusing.

The simple solution is (unless you need to work with very large sets of data):

Whenever you need to update any values, always make sure that you explicitly copy the DataFrame before the assignment.

```
df  # Some DataFrame
df = df.loc[:, 0:2]  # Some filtering (unsure whether a view or copy is returned)
df = df.copy()  # Ensuring a copy is made
df[df["Name"] == "John"] = "Johny"  # Assignment can be done now (no warning)
```

Comment: For large datasets you can make a shallow (deep=False) copy. Still it seems too much to suppress a warning.

Answer (score 25):

Just simply:

```py
import pandas as pd
# ...
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
```

Answer (score 20):

I had been getting this issue with `.apply()` when assigning a new dataframe from a pre-existing dataframe on which I've used the `.query()` method. For instance:

```
prop_df = df.query('column == "value"')
prop_df['new_column'] = prop_df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

Would return this error. The fix that seems to resolve the error in this case is by changing this to:

```
prop_df = df.copy(deep=True)
prop_df = prop_df.query('column == "value"')
prop_df['new_column'] = prop_df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

However, this is *not* efficient especially when using large dataframes, due to having to make a new copy.

If you're using the `.apply()` method in generating a new column and its values, a fix that resolves the error and is more efficient is by adding `.reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
prop_df = df.query('column == "value"').reset_index(drop=True)
prop_df['new_column'] = prop_df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 13):

To remove any doubt, my solution was to make a deep copy of the slice instead of a regular copy.
This may not be applicable depending on your context (Memory constraints / size of the slice, potential for performance degradation - especially if the copy occurs in a loop like it did for me, etc...)

To be clear, here is the warning I received:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:54:
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

### Illustration

I had doubts that the warning was thrown because of a column I was dropping on a copy of the slice. While not technically trying to set a value in the copy of the slice, that was still a modification of the copy of the slice.

Below are the (simplified) steps I have taken to confirm the suspicion, I hope it will help those of us who are trying to understand the warning.

#### Example 1: dropping a column on the original affects the copy

We knew that already but this is a healthy reminder. This is *NOT* what the warning is about.

```
>> data1 = {'A': [111, 112, 113], 'B':[121, 122, 123]}
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
>> df1

    A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123


>> df2 = df1
>> df2

A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123

# Dropping a column on df1 affects df2
>> df1.drop('A', axis=1, inplace=True)
>> df2
    B
0    121
1    122
2    123
```

It is possible to avoid changes made on df1 to affect df2. Note: you can avoid importing `copy.deepcopy` by doing `df.copy()` instead.

```
>> data1 = {'A': [111, 112, 113], 'B':[121, 122, 123]}
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
>> df1

A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123

>> import copy
>> df2 = copy.deepcopy(df1)
>> df2
A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123

# Dropping a column on df1 does not affect df2
>> df1.drop('A', axis=1, inplace=True)
>> df2
    A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123
```

#### Example 2: dropping a column on the copy may affect the original

This actually illustrates the warning.

```
>> data1 = {'A': [111, 112, 113], 'B':[121, 122, 123]}
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
>> df1

    A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123

>> df2 = df1
>> df2

    A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123

# Dropping a column on df2 can affect df1
# No slice involved here, but I believe the principle remains the same?
# Let me know if not
>> df2.drop('A', axis=1, inplace=True)
>> df1

B
0    121
1    122
2    123
```

It is possible to avoid changes made on df2 to affect df1

```
>> data1 = {'A': [111, 112, 113], 'B':[121, 122, 123]}
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
>> df1

    A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123

>> import copy
>> df2 = copy.deepcopy(df1)
>> df2

A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123

>> df2.drop('A', axis=1, inplace=True)
>> df1

A    B
0    111    121
1    112    122
2    113    123
```

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
quote_df.loc[:,'TVol'] = quote_df['TVol']/TVOL_SCALE
```

Answer (score 9):

Some may want to simply suppress the warning:

```
class SupressSettingWithCopyWarning:
    def __enter__(self):
        pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'warn'

with SupressSettingWithCopyWarning():
    #code that produces warning
```

Answer (score 8):

As this question is already fully explained and discussed in existing answers, I will just provide a neat *pandas* approach to the context manager using `pandas.option_context` (links to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html) and [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)) - there is absolutely isn't any need to create a custom class with all the [dunder methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word#Reserved_ranges) and other bells and whistles.

First the context manager code itself:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def SuppressPandasWarning():
    with pd.option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
        yield
```

Then an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_letters

a = pd.DataFrame({"A": list(ascii_letters[0:4]), "B": range(0,4)})

mask = a["A"].isin(["c", "d"])
# Even shallow copy below is enough to not raise the warning, but why is a mystery to me.
b = a.loc[mask]  # .copy(deep=False)

# Raises the `SettingWithCopyWarning`
b["B"] = b["B"] * 2

# Does not!
with SuppressPandasWarning():
    b["B"] = b["B"] * 2
```

It is worth noticing is that both approaches do not modify `a`, which is a bit surprising to me, and even a shallow df copy with `.copy(deep=False)` would prevent this warning to be raised (as far as I understand, shallow copy should at least modify `a` as well, but it doesn't. *pandas* magic.).

Answer (score 7):

You could avoid the whole problem like this, I believe:

```
return (
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(str_of_all), sep=',', names=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefg')) #dtype={'A': object, 'B': object, 'C': np.float64}
    .rename(columns={'A':'STK', 'B':'TOpen', 'C':'TPCLOSE', 'D':'TPrice', 'E':'THigh', 'F':'TLow', 'I':'TVol', 'J':'TAmt', 'e':'TDate', 'f':'TTime'}, inplace=True)
    .ix[:,[0,3,2,1,4,5,8,9,30,31]]
    .assign(
        TClose=lambda df: df['TPrice'],
        RT=lambda df: 100 * (df['TPrice']/quote_df['TPCLOSE'] - 1),
        TVol=lambda df: df['TVol']/TVOL_SCALE,
        TAmt=lambda df: df['TAmt']/TAMT_SCALE,
        STK_ID=lambda df: df['STK'].str.slice(13,19),
        STK_Name=lambda df: df['STK'].str.slice(21,30)#.decode('gb2312'),
        TDate=lambda df: df.TDate.map(lambda x: x[0:4]+x[5:7]+x[8:10]),
    )
)
```

Using Assign. From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html): Assign new columns to a DataFrame, returning a new object (a copy) with all the original columns in addition to the new ones.

See Tom Augspurger's article on method chaining in pandas: *[Modern Pandas (Part 2): Method Chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining)*

Answer (score 7):

This might apply to NumPy only, which means you might need to import it, but the data I used for my examples NumPy was not essential with the calculations, but you can simply stop this settingwithcopy warning message, by using this one line of code below:

```
np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: This one is the best one! Thanks. The copy warning is really annoying!

Answer (score 6):

#### Follow-up beginner question / remark

Maybe a clarification for other beginners like me (I come from [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) which seems to work a bit differently under the hood). The following harmless-looking and functional code kept producing the SettingWithCopy warning, and I couldn't figure out why. I had both read and understood the issued with "chained indexing", but my code doesn't contain any:

```
def plot(pdb, df, title, **kw):
    df['target'] = (df['ogg'] + df['ugg']) / 2
    # ...
```

But then, later, much too late, I looked at where the plot() function is called:

```
    df = data[data['anz_emw'] > 0]
    pixbuf = plot(pdb, df, title)
```

So "df" isn't a data frame, but an object that somehow remembers that it was created by indexing a data frame (so is that a view?) which would make the line in plot(),

```
 df['target'] = ...
```

equivalent to

```
 data[data['anz_emw'] > 0]['target'] = ...
```

which is a chained indexing.

Anyway,

```
def plot(pdb, df, title, **kw):
    df.loc[:,'target'] = (df['ogg'] + df['ugg']) / 2
```

fixed it.

Comment: A tad late to the party, but the `.loc` should probably go to `df = data[data['anz_emw'] > 0]`, not the `plot()` function.

Comment: This explanation was the only one that got through to me (maybe because I'm also coming from R). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you have assigned the slice to a variable and want to set using the variable as in the following:

```
df2 = df[df['A'] > 2]
df2['B'] = value
```

And you do not want to use [Jeff's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/20644369#20644369), because your condition computing `df2` is to long or for some other reason, then you can use the following:

```
df.loc[df2.index.tolist(), 'B'] = value
```

`df2.index.tolist()` returns the indices from all entries in df2, which will then be used to set column B in the original dataframe.

Comment: this is 9 time more expensive then df["B"] = value

Comment: Can you explain this more deeply @ClaudiuCreanga?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same warning, while I executed this part of my code:

```
def scaler(self, numericals):
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    self.data.loc[:, numericals[0]] = scaler.fit_transform(self.data.loc[:, numericals[0]])
    self.data.loc[:, numericals[1]] = scaler.fit_transform(self.data.loc[:, numericals[1]])
```

where `scaler` is a MinMaxScaler and `numericals[0]` contains names of three of my numerical columns.

The warning was removed as I changed the code to:

```
def scaler(self, numericals):
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    self.data.loc[:][numericals[0]] = scaler.fit_transform(self.data.loc[:][numericals[0]])
    self.data.loc[:][numericals[1]] = scaler.fit_transform(self.data.loc[:][numericals[1]])
```

So, *just* change `[:, ~]` to `[:][~]`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I would create a new column based on the index, but I got the same warning as you:

```
df_temp["Quarter"] = df_temp.index.quarter
```

I use insert() instead of direct assignment, and it works for me:

```
df_temp.insert(loc=0, column='Quarter', value=df_temp.index.quarter)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Why is this happening?

Selecting a list of columns and assigning it to a variable creates a copy. In pandas, slicing or indexing a dataframe creates a copy. But unlike function calls such as `filter()`, `query()` etc. that also create a copy, you can assign a value to a sliced or indexed dataframe, which becomes a problem as the new assignments (which are chained assignments) might not work. So the `SettingWithCopyWarning` is basically reminding you that you're assigning new values to a copy.

What is sometimes confusing is that it is *not raised* if an assignment on the copy doesn't change the shape of (or makes the copy to have the same shape as) the *original* dataframe.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = df1[df1['A']<3]        # <--- one row is filtered out
df2.loc[0, 'C'] = 1          # <--- SettingWithCopyWarning (because it is replacing a value on the copy)
df2.loc[3, 'C'] = 1          # <--- no warning (because it adds a new row which makes df2's shape the same as df1)
```

Same deal with filtering columns; changing a copy that is a subset of the original dataframe raises the warning but if the copy is no longer a subset, there is no warning.

```py
df2 = df1[['A']]               # <--- filters one column out
df2.loc[2, 'A'] = 100          # <--- SettingWithCopyWarning (tries to change a value on the copy)
df2['C'] = 100                 # <--- no warning (adds new column to copy)
```

### Solution: Enable Copy-on-Write

Since pandas 1.5.0, pandas has [Copy-on-Write (CoW)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/copy_on_write.html) mode that makes any dataframe/Series derived from another *behave* like a copy; so when it is enabled, values in a dataframe/Series can be changed only by modifying the object itself. One consequence is `SettingWithCopyWarning` will never be raised. Another is chained assignment never works. Also, a copy is created only if data is shared with another object (normally, most pandas methods create a copy which slows down the code), so pandas operations are faster with CoW.

This is planned to be the default behavior by pandas 3.0 but as of now, you have to turn it on.

To enable it globally,

```py
pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = True
```

or to turn it on locally with a context manager:

```py
with pd.option_context("mode.copy_on_write", True):
    # do operations
```

Example 1 (`SettingWithCopyWarning` is silenced):

```py
def func():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5), 'B': range(5,0,-1)})
    df1 = df[['B']]           # select a list of columns
    df1.loc[0, 'B'] = 1       # assign a value to the copy
    
func()                        # <---- SettingWithCopyWarning


pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = True
func()                        # <---- no warning
```

Example 2 (chained assignment doesn't work):

```py
pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = False
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5), 'B': range(5,0,-1)})
df['B'][df['A']<4] = 10     # <---- df changes; no warning
df[df['A']<4]['B'] = 10     # <---- df doesn't change; throws SettingWithCopyWarning



pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = True
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5), 'B': range(5,0,-1)})
df['B'][df['A']<4] = 10     # <---- df doesn't change; no warning
df[df['A']<4]['B'] = 10     # <---- df doesn't change; no warning
```

Example 3 (views are returned with chained methods, which improves performance a lot):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1_000_000), 'B': range(1_000_000)})

%%timeit
with pd.option_context('mode.copy_on_write', False):
    df.add_prefix('col ').set_index('col A').rename_axis('index col').reset_index()
# 30.5 ms ± 561 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit
with pd.option_context('mode.copy_on_write', True):
    df.add_prefix('col ').set_index('col A').rename_axis('index col').reset_index()
# 18 ms ± 513 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

This line at the beginning of my 'next steps' fixed the problem for me:

```
df = df.iloc[:] #To avoid SettingWithCopyWarning
```

Comment: This is a really clean solution that worked for me as well. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you found it useful :-)

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue occurred in a following *simplified* example. And I was also able to solve it (hopefully with a correct solution):

Old code with warning:

```
def update_old_dataframe(old_dataframe, new_dataframe):
    for new_index, new_row in new_dataframe.iterrorws():
        old_dataframe.loc[new_index] = update_row(old_dataframe.loc[new_index], new_row)

def update_row(old_row, new_row):
    for field in [list_of_columns]:
        # line with warning because of chain indexing old_dataframe[new_index][field]
        old_row[field] = new_row[field]
    return old_row
```

This printed the warning for the line `old_row[field] = new_row[field]`

Since the rows in update_row method are actually type `Series`, I replaced the line with:

```
old_row.at[field] = new_row.at[field]
```

I.e., [a method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.at.html) for accessing/lookups for a `Series`. Even though both works just fine and the result is same, this way I don't have to disable the warnings (=keep them for other chain indexing issues somewhere else).

Answer (score 1):

I use the **[`.loc` indexer (property)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)** to subset `DataFrame`s in order to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`s when manipulating the resulting subsets (such as `new_df` below):

```py
# GOOD way to select a columns subset:
new_df = df.loc[:, cols_subset]

#.. vs. bad way:
new_df = df[cols_subset]
# works but gives this warning:
# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
# Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a copy of your dataframe(s) using the `.copy()` method before the warning appears, to remove all of your warnings.

This happens, because we do not want to make changes to the original quote_df. In other words, we do not want to play with the reference of the object of the quote_df which we have created for quote_df.

```
quote_df = quote_df.copy()
```

Comment: This is needlessly a deep copy (default option is `deep=True`)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just use `PDCsv.loc[index, name]` = NewVal to realise the function:

```
PDCsv.loc[0, 'Name'] = 'Anthony Dave'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .copy() to create new df to avoid the warning.

```
df_new = quote_df.copy()
df_new['TVol'] = quote_df['TVol']/TVOL_SCALE
```